# What's the difference between '{}' and 'set()' in Python?

Tags: python, set

When I use

```py
a = {}
```

and

```py
a = set()
```

And sometimes I see use like:

```py
a = set([])
```

Are they the same? What's the difference between them?

I am asking because

```py
a = set(range(5))
b = {0,1,2,3,4}
a == b
>>> True
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an empty set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17663299/creating-an-empty-set)

Answer (score 5):

By default `{}` means an empty dictionary in python. However, the curly braces are used for both `dict` and `set` literals, see the following examples:

```py
empty_set = set()
non_empty_set = {1,2,3}
empty_dict = {}
empty_dict2 = dict()
non_empty_dict = {"a": 1}
```

avoid using

```py
a = set([]) # instead use a = set()
```

Answer (score 2):

When you initialise the variable with empty brackets it will be of type dict:

```
a = {}
print(f"type of a={type(a)}")
```

Output:

```
type of a=<class 'dict'>
```

However, if you initialise it with some values python will detect the type itself.

```
b = {1, 2, 3}
print(f"type of b={type(b)}")

c = {"some_key": "some_value"}
print(f"type of c={type(c)}")
```

Output:

```
type of b=<class 'set'>
type of c=<class 'dict'>
```

A set and a dictionary are two different data structures. You can read more about them here: [Beginner to python: Lists, Tuples, Dictionaries, Sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62708806/beginner-to-python-lists-tuples-dictionaries-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The literal `{}` will be a dictionary with key and value pairs, while `set()` is a set that contains just pure values. When using more than 0 elements, their literals will be distinguished by whether you include the key value pairs. For example, `{1: 'a', 2: 'b'}` vs `{1, 2}`.

Answer (score -1):

They are not the same.

`{}` creates and empty dictionary (but `{1,2,3}` creates a set with 3 elements: 1, 2, 3)

`set()` creates a empty set